# Cannot UrlFetch when the function is triggered

Tags: google-apps-script

I built the Google Apps Script application that fetches data through external API.

I get expected result when run this app, without any errors. However, when run it by Time-Driven Trigger, I get the error. Anyone know why this error occurs?

the code:

```
function triggerFetchTest() {

  // get token
  try {

    var id = "my_id",
        password = "my_password",
        tokenUrl = ("https://api.example.jp/v1/foo/auth/get_token?id=" + id
                     + "&password=" + password),
        tokenResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(tokenUrl);

    var token = JSON.parse(tokenResponse.getContentText())["token"];

    Logger.log(token);

  }

  catch(e) {

    Logger.log(e);

  }

}
```

---

Additionally:

- I can get correct response if I press "RUN" button in Script Editor.
- I don't have any problem setting trigger.
- I tried to set "muteHttpExceptions": true, but the error occurred.
- The code below that shown in [External APIs Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) is ok when even by triggered.

> var url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?'
>       + 'q=skateboarding+dog'
>       + '&start-index=21'
>       + '&max-results=10'
>       + '&v=2';
>       var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
>       Logger.log(response);

---

I want to set daily timer for this app and make the report automatically. Please give me some ideas.

---

**This post is my first post ever in Stackoverflow, and I'm not an English speaker in normal, so I'm sorry if you cannot read my English above...*

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Answer (score 0):

sama,
try to set your trigger by a function. First delete your trigger then add this function to your code and run it:

```
function setTrig(func){
  func=func||"triggerFetchTest";
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(func).timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
}
```

Something like this happened to me too can't remember exactly the explaination.

Comment: Harold,  
Thanks for your reply.  
I tried set the trigger programmatically as your advice, but it didn't work...  
  
  
`function everyDayTrigger() {  
ScriptApp.newTrigger("triggerFetchTest").timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();  
}`  
  
I've checked "Transcript", and it shows me that the running script failed at "UrlFetchApp.fetch()" point. I couldn't know anything else...

Answer (score 0):

Try making the main function a doGet() or doPost() and publishing the script as a web app with these settings: execute the app as me and let anyone, even anonymous access it. Then just create a another function that does a GET or POST request to your web app URI.

I think it works because the trigger does not run as you being logged in (something like AuthMode.NONE), it needs to be able to just do a urlFetch, which when you do on your app will invoke the doGet() or doPost() which is where all the work is done.

Example: https://gist.github.com/jbutters/bece2fffe85080fe4314

Answer (score 0):

The is an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=5&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=2758) related to Google Apps Script UrlFetch and Triggers. Please star it and leave comment on this open issue to force Google to do something about it.